# Три класа: библиотека,читатель, книга.Как сделать чтобы Клас библиотека управлял одолжеными и наявными книгами. Книги должны хранится в array

Tags: javascript, массивы, классы, наследование

```
    constructor(tytul_ksiazka,data_ksiazka,autor_ksiazka){
this.tytul_ksiazka=tytul_ksiazka;
this.data_ksiazka=data_ksiazka;
this.autor_ksiazka=autor_ksiazka;
 
}     
  wypozyczanie_k() {   
   return `Забрано книгу  ${this.tytul_ksiazka} `;
    }
  
  zwrucenie_k() {    
   return `Возвращено книгу ${this.tytul_ksiazka} `;
   
   }
}


class Czytelnik extends Ksiazka{
    constructor(id_czytelnik,imie_czytelnik,nazwisko_czytelnik,tytul_ksiazka,data_ksiazka,autor_ksiazka){
      
super(id_czytelnik,imie_czytelnik,nazwisko_czytelnik,tytul_ksiazka,data_ksiazka,autor_ksiazka);
      
this.id_czytelnik=id_czytelnik;
this.imie_czytelnik=imie_czytelnik;
this.nazwisko_czytelnik=nazwisko_czytelnik;
}
 
   wypozyczanie_k() { 
    super.wypozyczanie_k();
    return `Читатель  ${this.imie_czytelnik} взял книгу  `;
    }
  
   zwrucenie_k() {
     super.zwrucenie_k();
      return `Читатель ${this.imie_czytelnik} вернул книгу  `;
 
   }

}

class Biblioteka {
  constructor(wypozyczone,zwrucone){
 this.wypozyczone=[];  //масив с одолжеными  книгами
 this.zwrucone=[];     //масив с возвращеными  книгами
}}

const  ksiazka0 =new Ksiazka("Anna Karenina",1981,"Lew Tolstoj");
const ksiazka1 =new Ksiazka("Malenki Prins",1977,"Antuan-de-Sent Eksiuperi");

const czytelnik0=new Czytelnik(000,"Artur","Pierozkow");
const czytelnik1=new Czytelnik(011,"Piotr","Iwaszkiewicz");

console.log(czytelnik0.zwrucenie_k());
console.log(ksiazka0.zwrucenie_k());
console.log(czytelnik1.wypozyczanie_k());
console.log(ksiazka1.wypozyczanie_k());
```

Comment: а почему читатель от книги наследуется?

Comment: не получилось другим способом установить связь между читателем и книгой логично было бы через библиотеку но не хватает еще знаний

Comment: Связь читателя и книги в том, что он её может иметь. Например как свойство. но не как предка. И книг у одного читателя может быть много (массив нужен), наследование не подойдёт. Не думаю что библиотека должна связывать читателя и книгу, бывают книги не из библиотек. В библиотеке может быть массив просто имеющихся книг, а не возвращённых. А вот для одолженных массив логичен, потому что нужно их как-то затребовать например или знать что они где-то.

Comment: А вообще можно только один массив в библиотеке делать, как единый реестр. А уже у каждой книги будет свойство кому она одолжена, или null если никому (лежит в библиотеке). Но для всего этого нужно сначала знать ваши задачи, вариантов может быть много.

Comment: 1Нужен масив для хранения книг в класе библиотека,             2. метод для одолжения и возврата книг читателем ,при этом должно так и  остатся три класа и свойства конструкторов без изменений